# How does "Add Comment" javascript/AJAX work on stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was just looking at the code in firebug and I can't follow it. I can't figure out how clicking "add comment" calls the `jquery` function that shows the comment form. On my site I am trying to mimic this behavior. I have a registration form and I want a link such as "Fill in my data" which then displays a text input below the link where they enter a code, and then a submit button that through `AJAX` populates the fields. I am new to `js` and `AJAX`, but am a quick learner so I was hoping to get some clarity here on the details of implementation. Seems to me the displaying of the input field should not be `AJAX`, but just `js`. And then submit would trigger the `AJAX` function. I know `AJAX` is fairly involved, in terms of having to create an `xml` that describes the server side data that needs to be collected and then somehow submit button will trigger call to server side `php script` or something. Conceptually I understand, but mechanically I don't... Thanks! Brian

I just tried implementing as described, but the url is not triggering the js. Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".previousreg-link").on("click", function( event ){
event.preventDefault();                // Prevents browser following #hash 
$(this).hide();                        // hide the button
$(".previousreg-form-container").show();   // Show the form parent
});

$(".previousreg-form-container form").on("submit", function( event ){
  event.preventDefault();              // Don't send headers
  alert( $(this).serialize() +"\nWILL BE SENT TO PHP" );
 // $.ajax stuff
 });

 });
 </script>

 <a href=# class=previousreg-link>Use previous registration data</a>
 <div class="previousreg-form-container dno">
 <form>
 <textarea name=previousreg></textarea>
 <input type=submit>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Because my site already loads jquery I didn't add the script declaration for jquery. Is anything above obviously wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You probably could have worked this out with Firebug (or another in-browser debug app).

Answer (score 4):

Here in StackOverflow, the form is already present, **but hidden** initially (to save valuable space).
(StackOverflow uses a `.dno` class to hide elements.)

The click on the `add a comment` button does simply:

- hide the clicked `add a comment` button
- show the DIV holding the `form`

**A simple way to do it:**

```js
$(function(){

  $(".comments-link").on("click", function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();                // Prevents browser following #hash 
    $(this).hide();                        // hide the button
    $(".comment-form-container").show();   // Show the form parent
  });

  $(".comment-form-container form").on("submit", function( event ){
      event.preventDefault();              // Don't send headers
      alert( $(this).serialize() +"\nWILL BE SENT TO PHP" );
     // $.ajax stuff
  });

});
```

```css
.dno{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href=# class=comments-link>add a comment</a>
<div class="comment-form-container dno">
  <form>
    <textarea name=comment></textarea>
    <input type=submit>
  </form>
</div>
```

#### Regarding the `$.ajax`

since by submitting the form we don't want the page to refresh, AJAX is used to `POST` data to a PHP (let'ssay: `saveComment.php` page) which than stores to database. AJAX returns than a message ***response*** from the PHP code:

```
$.ajax({
  type    : "POST",
  url     : "saveComment.php",
  data    : $(this).serialize(),      // `this` is our form
  success : function( response ) {    // Response is the PHP echo
    alert("PHP says: "+ response);
    // Using jQuery append the message to 
  }
});
```

#### The PHP stuff

in the code above AJAX will POST a serialized data to PHP like:

```
comment=Please, show what you tried!
```

The `saveComment.php` than might look like:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') exit; // Don't allow anything but POST



$response = "";

if ( isset($_POST["comment"]) ) { 
     $commment = htmlspecialchars( $_POST["comment"] );
  // TODO: $userId = retrieve here the user ID from the session;
  // Sanitize(!!!!!) and save to database $comment and $userId
     $response = $commment;     
} else {
     $response = "Please, enter a comment";
}
echo $response;  // This will be sent/returned to AJAX
exit;
```

above, whatever you put in the `echo`, it will be returned by AJAX into the `response` argument.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to have to carefully look at everything you wrote. The thing that was confusing me in firebug was that I did not see an onclick event for that particular <a href>, only for the one right below it. So I don't have to use an xml file? I can just have php return a data array?

Comment: exactly. You can create XML for rss  or other stuff, but you don't need it for storing values into database or returning an array or json back to JS

Comment: I figured out my problem above. For some reason on my joomla site, it only works when I have the first line as jQuery(document).ready(function($) {